# Efficient way to test Cordova Application

Tags: android, cordova, debugging, testing

I'm developing android application using Cordova technology.
I also work with text editor and cli and I do not prefer to use Cordova via Visual Studio.

Every time I need to test the application, I need to launch `cordova run android` and it takes much time to install the app on the device.

Another way to test the application is using taco with livereload command `taco run android --livereload`. However the livereload is buggy when after some changes happen, resulting the app wont work (it throw `EPERM` errors or `Cannot get index.html`)

The alternative is using Ripple Emulator, however when I made changes, the whole ripple modules must be reloaded and sometimes it failed to load for unknown reasons, I also can't integrate this with task runner with gulp.

Now I'm clueless how to test application efficiently without taking much time on compiling / building and installing.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm struggling same issue about few weeks ago.
And also, TACO seems no longer maintained recently, check my [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TACO/issues/309#issuecomment-247468584) on TACO repo for more information.

You might interested with [cordova-simulate](https://github.com/microsoft/cordova-simulate). It is the same package that they use for the simulation of [Cordova Tools for Visual Studio Code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cordova)

Note that livereload might only work on Browser Simulation, I never attempt to use any livereload function on real device debugging.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I tried cordova simulate and  it seems helps me a lot!